# Best Windows language for multitouch and large bitmaps?

Tags: c#, silverlight, unity-container, processing, interactive

I will be developing an interactive application, involving multitouch, several layers of large bitmaps, and video playback. The screen resolution will be fairly large (1920x1280).

For several years, I have developed interactives in Flash, iOS, and OS X Cocoa. However, this project must run on a Windows box, so iOS & Cocoa are impossible. Also, I'm concerned about performance in Flash, since there may be 3 videos playing simultaneously, and large bitmaps moving around.

I know little about the technologies available on Windows. I'm investigating Silverlight, C#, Unity, Processing, and Java. If anyone can offer advice, it will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be investigating several technologies on different levels:

- C# and Java are programming languages. What you prefer may depend on your existing skills, but C# is from Microsoft so chances are that you will experience less friction using this language if you develop for Windows. Picking the right programming language is an important decision.
- Silverlight is a "technology stack" from Microsoft. It enables you to develop XAML based applications that run in the browser. Compared to the native WPF stack it is less powerful. Choosing Silverlight, WPF or another technology stack like Processing.js is an important decision.
- Unity is a dependency injection container from Microsoft. You can use this or any other suitable container if you like. Or none at all. You don't really have to think about this until you have made some of the more important decisions about your project.

Personally, I don't have experience with the type of application you describe, but I would go with C# and WPF. WPF has some support for multitouch on Windows, and only if it isn't adequate for your requirements you need to to go native and develop in say C++ which tends to require more work.

Multitouch in Windows 8 has been redesigned but unless you want to develop for a yet to be release operating system this is not an option.

Comment: Thank you. This is a great response. I should have written, "Best Windows _technology_"! Thanks for pointing me towards C# and WPF, also I have C++ experience so that's also workable.

Answer (score 1):

Use Visual C++ if you like to create a LAN based Application, C++ is known for it's power and you could have many resources that could help you in developing this application. If you're going to create this application for web Use ASP.net(C#) C# is known for its flexibility and class libraries dedicated for web and client appilcation i also advice the use of WPF and Silverlight applications.

Comment: Thanks Allan. I should have mentioned, this will not be a web app. The only input will be the multitouch surface.

Comment: No Problem buddy every body here in stack overflow shares

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you have a look at Windows 8 and Metro Apps. Here is a link to start with this: [The Microsoft BUILD conference, Windows 8, and the new UX Challenge](http://emergingexperiences.com/2011/09/microsoft-build-windows-8/). C# (.NET languages in fact), HTML5 and XAML are clearly the direction. Native C++ is back in town with WinRT. Silverlight is now in the gray area :-)

Even if you don't use Windows 8, it will give you a good overview of multitouch future in the Windows space.

Comment: Yes, This will be very helpful also :) nice one simon